# using Jackson to produce a json schema from a class, what do I need to do to the given output?

Tags: java, jackson, jsonschema

I want to create a JsonSchema file from my java classes using latest Jackson libraries .

When I have a java class like the following:

```
class MyClass {
    String status;
}
```

how do I need to annotate the field so that the schema output would look like this:

```
{
   ...
   "status": {
       "description": "status",
       "type": [ "string", "null" ],
       "maxLength":12                   
   }, ...
}
```

?

Cheers

Comment: You may find helpful the Jackson JSON schema module: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema .

Comment: I did not find the necessary information in that documentation, that is why I asked here.